# Example of continuous increasing and decreasing functions that don't intersect.

Tags: continuity

I am looking to describe two continuous functions. One of them is strictly increasing on the real line and one of them is strictly decreasing on the real line. I want to describe these functions in terms of non-exponential and non-trigonometric elementary functions.

I have this constraint because in my real analysis course these functions have not been introduced yet.

I wrote the problem off as easy but now I realize that I would not know how to solve it.

Comment: Are you assuming the decreasing function starts greater than the increasing function, but ends less than?

Comment: No, just non-intersecting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|}$$

and move it up and down, and reflect it, to get two continuous monotone functions that don't cross each other.

Comment: Now I have to figure out why this didn't come to me in the first place. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 2-x & \quad \text{ in }(-\infty, 1] \\ 
       1/x & \quad \text{  in }[1,\infty) \end{cases}$$ 
$$
g(x)= \begin{cases}x-2 & \quad \text{ in }(-\infty, 1]\\
      -1/x & \quad \text{  in } [1,\infty) \end{cases}$$

Comment: See [MathJax help](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020)

Comment: thank you I need to get the hang of the formatting

Answer (score 0):

Take the lines $y=x+1, y=-x-1$ in $[0,\infty)$ and smooth them out in $(-\infty,0]$, so that they both approach $0$ ,from above, below respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Take any two cdfs of continuous increasing r.v.s on $(-\infty,\infty)$ ($F_1, F_2$) that don't involve the functions you're trying to avoid. Then $F_1(x)$ and ($k-F_2(x)$) (for $k$ outside $(0,2)$) should work.

So for example $F_1 = \frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{x}{1+|x|})\,,$ for $-\infty<x<\infty$ would do.

Alternatively, getting away from distribution functions, something like $\sqrt{1+x^2/4}+x/2$ and its negative would work.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = \arctan x \;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\; g(x) = \pi - \arctan x$$